# How to Deal with Namespacing URLs in a Reusable Django App

Tags: django, django-urls

I have been struggling with reversing URLs with a reusable Django app. Here's the basic layout of my problem.

**Reusable App:**

In the `urls.py` file it has the following pattern:

```
url(r'^object-list/$', ObjectListView.as_view(), name='object-list')
```

Somewhere in the reusable app's `views.py`, there is the following reverse call:

```
reverse('object-list')
```

---

**My Project:**

In the project where I want to use this app, I have another conflicting view name, so I namespace the app's URLs like so:

```
url(r'^app-stuff/', include('app.urls', namespace='app'))
```

---

**The Problem:**

This has the consequence of causing all reverse calls within the app to throw a `NoReverseMatch` exception when it tries to lookup `object-detail`, because the URL now has the name `app:object-detail`.

I have access to the app in question, so I can modify the calls it makes to `reverse`, but I would like to do it in a way that doesn't involve hardcoding a namespace. I have read the documentation on the `current_app` and `namespace` arguments to the `include` function but I don't quite understand if they would help solve the issue I'm having.

Any suggestions you might have are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this after reading [Django's docs on URL resolution](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#topics-http-reversing-url-namespaces) more closely.

If you have a reusable app called `myapp`, you can add the property `app_name` to its URL configuration to give it an application namespace. Example:

```
# myapp/urls.py

app_name = 'myapp'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index')
]
```

Now, even if the app's URLs are included like so:

```
# project/urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='random-namespace')),
]
```

...the urls are still accessible using `reverse('myapp:index')`.

If you would like to see this in more detail, I created [a small GitHub repo with an example](https://github.com/smalls12/namespace_issues).

**Edit:**

Specifying the `app_name` property in `urls.py` only works on Django 1.9 and up. For Django 1.8, you have to use the `app_name` parameter in the `include()` function.

Comment: Thanks. However, this solution doesn't seem to work for nested apps.

Comment: @pymarco Can you provide any more information on that? If possible, could you make a pull request to the [repo](https://github.com/cdriehuys/namespace_issues) that shows the problem?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I just posted a separate SO question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709613/reverse-url-in-reusable-app-that-is-consumed-as-a-nested-app