# Reverse url in reusable app that is consumed as a nested app

Tags: django, django-urls

A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060270/how-to-deal-with-namespacing-urls-in-a-reusable-django-app).

My situation is slightly different though. I have created a reusable app called "categories". In my project I have an app called "dashboard". The dashboard app includes the reusable "categories" app. This causes the following to be used to reverse a url

```
reverse('dashboard:categories:browse')
```

However, my reusable app has no knowledge of the "dashboard" namespace. I want to be able to use the solution I linked above to reverse only the following within the reusable categories app.

```
reverse('categories:browse')
```

Currently, setting `app_name` in categories.urls does not work. I get `NoReverseMatch` when reversing "categories:browse".

Here are excerpts of how the apps are included in the urls.py files.

```
# myproject/urls.py
url(
    r'^dashboard/',
    include(
        'dashboard.urls',
        namespace='dashboard',
    )
),


# dashboard/urls.py
url(
    r'^categories/',
    include(
        'categories.urls',
        namespace="categories",
    ),
),
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of `urls.py`.

Comment: no problem, just updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the `categories` urls in your main `urls.py` directly:

```
# myproject/urls.py
url(r'^dashboard/categories/', include('categories.urls', namespace='categories')),
url(r'^dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls', namespace='dashboard')),
```

That way your `categories` urls are not in a nested namespace, and you can simply use `reverse('categories:browse')`.

Comment: That works, thank you! I guess I would have preferred everything neatly tucked away in the dashboard app. But I'm happy to have a working solution.